# Почему в средах разработки QtCreator и MonoDevelop под Linux некорректно работает ввод/вывод?

Tags: c, monodevelop, qt, ubuntu

upd.: Переименовал вопрос. Из-под терминала код работает.

Предпринял попытку переселиться на Linux (xubuntu 12.10 x64) c Windows. Первым делом были установлены среды разработки QTcreator и MonoDevelop и была написана простенькая программа для теста. Суть программы заключается в выдаче пользователю n случайных чисел от 1 до m пока не будет введён 0. Код:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

int dN(int N);   
void MdN(int M, int N);

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int m = 1, n = 0;
    int c;
    srand(time(NULL));
    while (m != 0)
    {
        printf("\nВведите два числа (количество и количество граней дайсов) или 0 для выхода\n");
        m = 0;
        c = scanf("%d", &m);
        if (c != 1)
        {
             puts("Ошибка ввода");
             return 0;
        }
        if (m != 0)
        {
            n = 0;
            while (n == 0)
            {
                printf("\b\bd");
                c = scanf("%d", &n);
                if (c != 1)
                {
                     puts("Ошибка ввода");
                     return 0;
                }
            }
            MdN(m, n);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

int dN(int N)
{
    return rand()%N + 1;
}

void MdN(int M, int N)
{
    int s = 0, tmp;
    while (M>0)
    {
        s += tmp = dN(N);
        printf("+%d", tmp);
        M--;
    }
    printf("=%d;\r \n", s);
}
```

В обеих средах код работал неверно. В QtCreator программа бесконечно запрашивала ввод (в т.ч. и символьного типа). В MonoDevelop программа не запрашивала (и не ожидала) ввод, но выводила

```
\nВведите два числа (количество и количество граней дайсов) или 0 для выхода\n

Ошибка ввода
```

(выполнялось c==EOF).

Устанавливал среды через "Центр приложений Ubuntu", настроек по дефолту не менял.

//тут был ещё более простой код с той же проблемой

Comment: Попробуйте включить ctype.h

Comment: Не оказало влияния на работу программы.

Comment: @bessgeor, ну Вы меня прямо заинтересовали (последним маленьким кодом).

А что Вы от него ждете? Если печать введенного числа, то добавьте `%d` в соответствующий `printf()`.

Также советую завершать вывод символом '\\n'.

Comment: Забыл %d по неопытности и т.к. спешил. Исправил это, ситуация с некорректной работой программы сохранилась. Сейчас попробую применить флаги компилятора, как посоветовал KoVadim, может так смогу увидеть причину проблемы.

Comment: @bessgeor, как говорят в таких случаях, - чудес не бывает. Прекрасно Ваш последний примерчик работет под gcc, попробуйте его скомпилить и запустить на какой-нибудь другой машине с установленным Linux-ом, если есть такая возможность.

Comment: @bessgeor, а чтто значит **"некорректная работа ввода/вывода"?**

Вы опишите, что *ожидали* видеть на экране, а что *на самом деле* ***видите***.

Тогда можно и код смотреть.

А так, судя по

    while (isdigit(c = getchar()))
    {
        printf("%c", c);
        m *= 10;
        m += (c-49);
    }

Вы не очень понимаете, что код после `getchar()` начнет (в цикле, конечно) выполняться только после нажатия <ENTER>.

Кстати, зачем от `c` отнимать 49? Десятичный код ascii

Comment: >> Кстати, зачем от c отнимать 49? Десятичный код ascii

вообще то нужно 48 вычитать.

Comment: Вернул scanf, в работе программы ничего не изменилось. Малый код попробовал скомпилировать под другой машиной (система та же, но x86). Изменения проявились только в Mono, который теперь не вывел ничего, кроме двух \n. Может стоит выложить конфигурации компьютеров?

Comment: По поводу вывода ожидаемого и реального (по основному коду).

Ожидаемый:

Enter two numbers (MdN) or zero to exit\n

//ожидание ввода числа, если число не ноль

Enter non-zero N

//ожидание ввода числа, если число не ноль

 [случайное число]+[случайное число]+...=[сумма случайных чисел]\n

Реальный
QT: бесконечное ожидание ввода, вводить можно что угодно.
Mono:

Enter two numbers (MdN) or zero to exit\n

0\n

Comment: @bessgeorg, ну а теперь замените в

    if (c == 1)
    {
        puts("Input error");
        ....


c == 1 на c != 1,

глядишь и лучше станет.

Comment: @bessgeor, все еще не заработало?

Попробуйте перед 

    while (n == 0) 

обнулять n (а то ведь n один только раз (первый, когда она еще 0) и вводится).

После "debug output" fflush(stdout) напишите, а то буферизация вывода до чтения stdin (или вывода \\n) происходит. (А лучше просто \\n в этот printf() добавьте).

Ну, не считая дискутируемого srand() прямо перед rand(), вроде все. В нормальном терминале должна заработать.

Answer (score 5):

Вероятнее всего, Ваша проблема кроется в функции scanf(), т.к. данная функция завершает считывание числа, когда встречает первый нечисловой символ ([link](http://lord-n.narod.ru/download/books/walla/programming/Spr_po_C/08/0805.htm)), соответственно, у Вас в основном цикле:

1. переменная m остается равной своему предыдущему значению,
2. после введенный символ пробует считаться еще раз, не считывается снова, и в n остается либо предыдущее значение, либо мусор,
3. выполняются действия для неадекватных m и n, но введенный символ никуда из потока ввода не делся, и происходит зацикливание.

Есть у Вас и еще ошибка - Вы не проверяете значение, сохраняемое в n, а в функции dN() делите на него, хотя никто не мешает ввести вторым запрашиваемым числом - 0.

Comment: Переделал (изменил код в вопросе) ввод под использование getchar(). Проблема сохранилась в том же виде, за исключением того, что в MonoDevelop зацикливания больше не происходит и вывод происходит лишь один раз (т.к. в теле цикла перед вводом m приравнивается 0, а ввода не происходит).

Comment: компилила с getchar() в gcc, все там нормально вводится... попробуйте еще проще примерчик запустить просто с вводом чилел и их последующей печатью.
KoVadim прав, все-таки стоит пользоваться тем же scanf(), но с проверкой результата, дабы избежать зацикливания.

Comment: gcc генерирует исполняемый файл, запуск которого ни к чему не ведёт

Comment: @margosh, Вы что, поиздеваться над новичком (это о совете заменить scanf на getchar) решили?

--

Оно, конечно, можно (в конце-то концов свой scanf получится), но все-таки для ввода чисел **значительно проще** изучить, как использовать scanf из библиотеки.

Comment: @avp, нет, я решила,что автор просто проверяет ввод,и раз с использованием scanf() было сразу не разобраться(в изначальной версии он все зацикливал), то проще пользоваться getchar(), но если корень проблемы в считывании именно чисел, то она неудобна. Поправлю ответ, чтобы это больше никого не сумщало.

Answer (score 5):

Посмотрел код, стало страшно. Вот мой вариант (написан в лоб, по факту можно было бы вынести в отдельные функции)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int dN(int N)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    return rand()%N + 1;
}

void MdN(int M, int N)
{
   printf("==== MdN(%d,%d)===\n", M, N); // это для отладки
    int s = 0, tmp;
    if (N == 0) // защита, Ваш код падал при нуле
      return;
    while (M>0)
    {
        s += tmp = dN(N);
        printf("+%d", tmp);
        M--;
    }
    printf("=%d;\r \n", s);
}

int main()
{
    int m = 0;
    int n = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        printf("Enter two numbers (MdN) or zero to exit\n");
        int r = scanf("%d", &m); // ввод первого
        if (r != 1) {
          puts("first number is not numer\n");
          break;
        }
        if (m == 0) {
            // пользователь ничего не ввел либо ввел один ноль
            puts("exit\n");
            break;
        }

        // удалось прочитать только одно число. Попробуем прочитать ещё одно
        r = scanf("%d", &n);
        if (r != 1) {
            puts("ups, second number is not number\n");
            break;
        }

        MdN(m,n);
    }
    printf("end\n");
    return 0;
}
```

scanf возвращает результат и корректно будет проверять, что он возвратил. По факту - возвращается количество переменных, которые удалось вычитать. 0 - если ничего не прочитали. Те переменные, которые удалось прочитать, будут иметь значения. Если случится что то странное, `scanf` возвратит -1 (по честному - константу `EOF`).

Можно делать ввод в виде `sscanf("%d %d", &m, &n)`. Но если пользователь введет только один ноль, то код будет ждать, пока будет введет ещё один символ. Поэтому я разбил ввод на две части.

> > Как ни странно, в обеих средах код работал неверно.

логично, так как с 99% вероятностью компилятор один и тот же - gcc.

> > Для Вашего случая больша подошла бы getchar() с проверкой введенного значения

очень вредный совет. С `int` еще проверку сделаете, а с `float`?

Почему же оно работает в Visual studio? есть подозрение, что там `sscanf("%d %d", &m, &n)` при вводе одно числа и перевода строки возвращает 1 и заполненное `m`.

**upd**

Учитывая последние изменения в примере в вопросе.  Если Вы только начинаете изучать С и делаете много ошибок (зачастую элементарных), то нужно компилятору намекнуть, что нужно быть строже. Да, он будет придираться по пустякам, но на первое время самое оно.

Я рекомендую такой наборчик

```
-std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-qual -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes
```

Как использовать:

- если это в консоли, то просто `gcc имяфайла.с -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-qual -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes
- если это monodevelop. В дереве "решений" слева выделяете свой проект, кликаете правой, "свойства", в окне "свойства проекта" находите "Генерация кода", выбираете вкладку с таким же именем и внизу видите окно "Extra Compiler Options", куда и вставляете вышеприведенный список.
- В QtCreator нужно открыть pro файл и добавить туда строку вида `QMAKE_CFLAGS = -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-qual -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes`

Что значат эти флаги?

- `std=c99` следовать стандарту с99. Сейчас есть и другие, но этот более промышленный (но это мое мнение)
- `pedantic` быть попридирчивей
- `Wall` включает большой набор проверок. К примеру придерется к коду вида `if (a = 0)` (некоторые любители любят это лечить переворачиванием условия, а некоторые используют для сознательного запутывания). Также эта опция включает `-Wformat`, который заставляет компилятор пересчитывать параметры у функций вида `printf/scanf` и ругаться, если их не хватает или типы не совпадают.
- `Wshadow` придираться, когда в функции используется перекрывание переменных. К примеру, внутри функции объявляется переменная, имя которой совпадает с параметром. В некоторых случаях может приводить к веселым ошибкам.
- `Wpointer-arith` в новых версиях это уже включается в `-pedantic`. Придирается, когда с химичат с арифметикой указателей.
- `Wcast-qual` придирается, когда делается приведение типов, которое потенциально опасное. это часто вылазит у новичков, когда они осваивают работу со строками в стиле с.
- `Wstrict-prototypes` придерется к `int main()`, так как желательно писать `int main(int argc, char ** argv)`.
- `Wmissing-prototypes` потребует определять прототипы используемых функций. То есть, добавлять строки вида `int dN(int N);`.

Конечно, некоторые найдут эти вещи абсурдными и мешающими (особенно для "продвинутых программистов"). Но я в своих проектах время от времени включаю подобные наборы и смотрю - не вылезло ли глупостей - опечатку то сделать легко.

На первый порах рекомендую  все эти замечания компилятора устранять.

Comment: в данной теме задачи считывания float не стоит, поэтому getchar() считаю вполне уместным.

Comment: а сделать проверку на переполнение, а сделать ввод отрицательных чисел? Ввод через getchar в данном случае - это велосипед.

Comment: глянула внимательнее, пожалуй, вы правы, проверка результата выполнения scanf() - более красивый вариант избежать зацикливания

Comment: Попробовал использовать ваш код (который, согласен, выглядит лучше), проблема сохранилась. К тому же проблема возникает и в ещё более простом коде (см. выше). Может ли это быть связано с некой спецификой платформы?

Comment: Попробовал применить предложенные вами флаги. QT и MonoDevelop спокойно позволили собрать код ("малая" задача, в том виде, как она представлена выше). Не смотря на флаг Wstrict-prototypes. GCC позволил собраться, но вывел предупреждение. После добавления приёма аргументов (int argc, char** argv) предупреждений выводить не стал. В целом же ситуация сохранилась: GCC всё так же генерирует ничего не делающий (предположение, отсутствует видимость действий), QT читает всё подряд, Mono выводит всё подряд не запрашивая ввода (пример вывода есть в комментарии на ответ progzdeveloper ниже).

Comment: Выводить предупреждения или считать их за ошибку - это регулируется другими параметрами. Иногда компилятор может и не понять юмор программиста.

Кажется я понимаю, почему у Вас такие проблемы. Суть их заключается в том, что Вы ожидаете одно поведение (которое Вам кажется логичным), но на самом деле все ведет себя по другому.

QtCreator и MonoDevelop используют перенаправление ввода-вывода. Но подозреваю, что делают они это по разному. Поэтому рекомендую подобные вещи вначале запускать в отдельной консоли и там смотреть. А потом уже угадывать, почему IDE работает по другому.

Comment: Наверное  я невнимательно все посмотрел, но IMHO в

    int dN(int N)
    {
        srand(time(NULL));
        return rand()%N + 1;
    }

**srand() не на месте**. 

При вызове dN() в цикле (без ожидания ввода с клавы) rand() одно и то же число (почти всегда) выдавать будет.

Comment: В данном случае это не должно давать описываемые автором вопроса проблемы.

Comment: @KoVadim, так автор свои проблемы и не описывает, можно только понять, что  он ожидал от проги чего-то другого, но что он видит - не пишет.

Почему-то думает, что игры с ключами компилятора что-то изменят.

Comment: Ключи компилятора, которые я привел, попытаются выявить часть ошибок, что бы ТС не переспрашивал о элементарных ошибках.

ТС пишет, что ему не нравиться и это точно не связано с srand.

Comment: Что есть tty и, тем более, режимы работы с tty я не знаю.
Игры с ключами компилятора могли указать на ошибку.
Нужен мне как-раз таки вывод С ожиданием ввода. Но (в Mono, компилятор gcc) не происходит ни ожидания ввода, ни, собственно, ввода. После исправления условия на "была прочитана не одна целочисленная переменная" для Input Error, он начал срабатывать.
Проблема (и то, что я вижу) заключается в том, что программа не ожидает и не осуществляет ввод, когда (насколько мне известно) она должна и ожидать, и осуществлять ввод.

Comment: @bessgeor, ну что же у Вас в самом деле не работает?  Вот скопипастил Ваш код (ничего в нем не трогал), собрал и запустил:


    avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ gcc t22.c
    avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ ./a.out 
    Enter two numbers (MdN) or zero to exit
    3
    3Enter non-zero N4
     2+2+2=6;
    Enter two numbers (MdN) or zero to exit
    5
    5Enter non-zero N6
     2+2+2+2+2=10;
    Enter two numbers (MdN) or zero to exit
    0
    0avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ 


Как видите ввод-вывод работает. Это Linux (Ubuntu 12.04.2,  gnome-terminal).

С \\n Вы, конечно, не дружите, но в принципе работает.

Comment: Сей код не работает в средах разработки с уже описанными мной проблемами. С компиляцией же из терминала сработало моё незнание системы. А именно то, что исполняемый файл я пытался запустить двойным кликом в файловом менеджере либо через терминал без предварительного ./

Comment: @bessgeor, советую переименовать вопрос в

    Среды разработки QTcreator и MonoDevelop в Linux полная лажа,
    или я что-то криво поставил?

Answer (score 1):

> Почему же оно работает в Visual studio

У мелкомягких все как не у людей

А вообще-то я советую компилить gcc из командной строки

Comment: @akalend: вы считаете, что то, что программа не работает — это нормально, так "у людей" и должно быть?

Answer (score 0):

Доброго времени суток! По поводу Ваше простой задачи(ввести число, вывести число), вы не корректно используете функцию printf - вы забыли передать форматную строку, в стандарте сказано, что при этом

> Программа будет иметь неопределенное поведение

Что вы и имеете на разных платформах (зависает, не выводит и т.п.)
Вот исправленный вариант:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a, b;
    printf("test output\n");
    b = scanf("%d", &a);
    if (b == EOF)
        puts("input error");
    // не забываем %d!
    printf("input test: %d", a);
    return 0;
}
```

Теперь по поводу самого вопроса, я не очень понял, что именно не так работает в Вашем коде? Просто у меня **исправленный код** Вашей программы работает вроде нормально, может я что-то не уловил?

Comment: В малой задаче исправление %d не помогло. Проблема заключается в следующем: во всех версиях кода, способных компилироваться
а) gcc генерирует исполняемый файл, запуск которого ни к чему не ведёт
б) QT Creator открывает окно терминала и читает в нём всё подряд ничего не выводя
в) MonoDevelop не запрашивая ввода выводит всё что может (на что не стоит однозначно false условий, например, 1!=1). Например, выполнение вашего кода, приведённого выше приводит к такому вот выводу:

test output

input error


input test: 0

Comment: Посмотрите, может это поможет: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255035/qt-creator-run-in-terminal